# remove query string key=value at webserver level (apache/nginx)

Tags: apache, facebook, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I would like to remove

```
fb_xd_fragment
```

from the query string and pass the rest of the request off to the application level. This is for an improved cache hit rate so doing this modification at the application level is not useful nor possible (trust me). Example of how to modify the query string using apache or nginx would be nice.

Example input values

```
example.com/abcd?page=2&fb_xd_fragment
example.com/abcd?fb_xd_fragment
example.com/abcd?fb_xd_fragment&page=4
example.com/abcd?fb_xd_fragment=xyz&page=6
example.com/abcd?page=8&fb_xd_fragement=xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

With mod_rewrite, a RewriteRule can't be used to match a query string, but you can apply a RewriteCond to spot a target query string. Crucially, you can backreference matches in the RewriteCond in the rewrite rule, so try something along these lines:

```
#     we can refer to this----+-----------------and this--+
#     match as %1 in the      |              match as %2  |
#     RewriteRule             |                           |
                              v                           v
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)fb_xd_fragment=?[a-z]*&?(.*)$
RewriteRule /abcd /abcd?%1%2
```

The %*x* in the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is a backreference to the last matched [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). You might need to play around with this to get exactly the effect you want, but you should see the basic principle. Good luck :)

Comment: any chance of setting an environment variable and using that else where?

RewriteRule .* - [E=FILTERED_QUERY:%1%2]

Answer (score 1):

This parameter is actually symptomatic of Facebook Connect or a Like button doing bad things. You can avoid it altogether by configuring the javascript correctly.

http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/facebook-connect-ie-fb_xd_fragment-iframe/